# MS Access VBA SendObject

Tags: vba, ms-access

So, I'm in the middle of self-study (watching YouTube) MS access VBA and would like to create a custom report. Output will be, choose specific person(using combo box) to whom would I like to send it to. Then by clicking the button an email will pop out with attached of the file that I'd like to send. however, when I use the code below. the "To" appears as number not email address. (please see image below link)

```
Private Sub Command3_Click()

  DoCmd.SendObject acSendQuery, "EOD_Report", acFormatXLS, Me.Combo18, , , "Test Report" & Month(Date) & Day(Date) & Year(Date), "Attached are today's test report", True

End Sub
```

[image]

Looking forward on your help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the To argument you used:

```
Me.Combo18
```

This will send the Value of the selection (The bound column) not the text. The bound column could be the ID of the person saved in your database so it will be a number

You may instead use:

```
Me.Combo18.Column(1)
```

Assuming you put the e-mail address in the second column and ID in the first column (The bound column)